# MudBlazor class align-content-end not working

Tags: mudblazor

I'm trying to build a form with descriptions after every fields.

I want it to be like this:

Label
Values here                   Descriptions here

---

But it looks like this now:

Label                      Descriptions here
Values here

---

I found something about class align-content-end here:https://www.mudblazor.com/utilities/align-content#basic-usage-end
But seems it doesn't work in MudGrid and MudItems.

Here is my code:

```
<MudGrid Style="width: 100%;">
    <MudItem xs="12" md="3">
        <MudTextField Disabled For="@(() => Model!.Id)" @bind-Value="Model!.Id" Label="@Localizer["Id"]" ReadOnly="true"
                      Margin="Margin.Dense"/>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" md="9" Class="align-content-end">
        <MudText Color="Color.Surface" Style="vertical-align: bottom;">
            <small>Descriptions</small>
        </MudText>
    </MudItem>
```

Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the `MudItem` to a flex and align-items:end == `d-flex align-end`

```
<MudItem xs="12" md="9" Class="d-flex align-end">
    <MudText Color="Color.Surface">
        <small>Descriptions</small>
    </MudText>
</MudItem>
```

[Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEQxuLuLAacQGARR)

Comment: Great and thanks! It works as a charm. And it turned out that if the MudField is  a DateTime? or Select, the position of the description will be too low. Class="d-flex align-end mb-1" makes it perfect then.